# Teste selenium parado

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Estou com um problema que o selenium para quando aparece um loader na minha tela(A minha aplicação que esta sendo testada também para). Ele fica parado infinito e não da time-out.

Gostaria de saber se tem como colocar um tempo limite para executar um teste?

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada [nesse link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/).

Ele ensina sobre os métodos `.implicit_wait()`, `.explicit_wait()` e `.fluent_wait()`.

Tem [esse tópico no SO_en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver) tbm que pode te ajudar.

Outra ideia, por exemplo, é utilizar uma `estrutura de repetição` com um `time.sleep()` dentro dela...

Answer (score 0):

Eu geralmente utilizo o `while`

este é um exemplo em python, mas só adaptar a sintaxe para a linguagem que tu ta usando.

```
while True:
    try:
       time.sleep(1)
       #faz um teste para saber se já passou 
       break
    except:
       # retorna o tipo do erro
```